# python3 increment value by keypress

Tags: python, python-3.x

This does not work. What am I doing wrong?
The error says x is undefined. I was trying to increment xx by one with an x keypress.

```
xx = int()
yy = int()
zz = int()
print(xx, yy, zz)

b = input("New value:")
if b == x:
    then [xx ++ 1]
    print(xx, yy, zz)
else :
    print(xx, yy, zz)
```

Comment: you defined `x` not `xx`.... and `xx = int()` ist just `xx = 0`. `b` will be a string, not an `int` and `b == xx` will always fail (oh, you meant `xx == 'x'`)... `then` is not part of the python language. and did you mean `xx += 1`?

Comment: I think you mean `if b=='x':` You want to check if `b` is equal to the string `'x'`, not a variable `x` that doesn't exist. Also, `then` is not a Python keyword.

Comment: 'x' as a string. Thank you. I removed the square braces and +=  works. Thank you again.

Comment: xx = int() and xx = 0 both increment to 1; xx = int(3) increments to 4, does python consider 0 a string until I increment it?

Comment: Please read a basic tutorial before asking here

Answer (score 0):

You have not defnied x and hence you wont get any increment

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
name = 0

xx = int()
yy = int()
zz = int()

while(name == 0):

    b = input("New value:")
    if b == 'x':
            xx += 1
            print(xx, yy, zz)
    elif b == 'y':
            yy += 1
            print(xx, yy, zz)
    elif b == 'z':
            zz += 1
            print(xx, yy, zz)
    elif b == '~':
            break
    else :
            print(xx, yy, zz)
            continue
```